# executing queries together to gain efficiency

Tags: mysql, database, jdbc

Presently I am using prepared statements to execute a query or an update on the database. Though pre-compiled(and hence fast) I think that it would be even more efficient if could have such an arrangement:

Scenario:

Suppose I have to insert 100 rows in a database table. I use prepare statements so I prepare a statement and send it to the database for execution. So each time the query is of the form:

```
insert into user values(....);
```

Now consider this situation when I have a query of the form

```
insert into user values (...), (...), ....,(...);
```

By this we can minimize table access and execute query in one go.

Is there any way that we can do this using prepared statements or such an arrangement where we can instruct database that execute next 100 updates together. By the way I am presently working on mysql

Comment: @AmanDeepGautem what is the table engine?, if you are working with innodb you can set autocommit=0 before start inserting, and when you are done just make "commit;"

Comment: yup engine is innodb. looks good, will give it a try. but is there no direct way that they support it. Is there a way that java supports that form of preparedstatement??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> INSERT statements that use VALUES syntax can insert multiple rows. To
>   do this, include multiple lists of column values, each enclosed within
>   parentheses and separated by commas. Example:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);
```

Try something like

```
st = con.createStatement();
  st.addBatch("INSERT INTO tbl_name VALUES(1,2,3)");
  st.addBatch("INSERT INTO tbl_name VALUES(4,5,6)");
  st.addBatch("INSERT INTO tbl_name VALUES(7,8,9)");
  st.executeBatch();
```

Comment: yes but this statement is not pre-compiled. This is the disadvantage in this approach.

Comment: addBatch and executeBatch give you the mechanism to perform batch inserts

Comment: You should use a PreparedStatement and executeBatch() to avoid repeating the same SQL literal over and over again.

Comment: I have edited the answer with an illustration of the above comment.

Answer (score 0):

Any reason not to do it as a [bulk insert](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) operation?

There's probably a better way of doing it, but I simply write a "file" to /dev/shm then reference in a LOAD DATA INFILE statement, thus never hitting disk on the client machine.